# refering the app after each time it closes

Tags: iphone

I am have an app in which I draw shape. When I close and open the application the drawn shapes remains. I want to know is there any way I could clear the contents on each launch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're not actually terminating the app, but backgrounding it. When you launch the application again, it continues from where you left off: showing the drawn shape.

If you'd like to clear the shape when the application moves from the background into the foreground, you could implement `applicationWillEnterForeground:` in `UIApplicationDelegate` (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground%3a)) or you could observe `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`s (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification)).

Answer (score 1):

Another tactic you can try is to add to your info.plist file: "Application does not run in background" and set it to YES.  This will force your app to quit instead of running in the background.

Unless you are running a simple app it would be better to use the methods recommended by Chris Doble and Lenny K.  Apple definitely prefers that apps take advantage of multitasking.  Seriously consider if this is best for your app.  But if you have a simple app or really want a completely clean start each time a user returns to it, then setting this variable in the plist file is quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @ChrisDoble was saying, you could also implement the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method so that as soon as the application is closed you can delete the drawn shapes.

If for whatever reason this doesn't work, try leaving the app and when on the home screen double-click the home button.  Several app icons should come up on the bottom.  Scroll through until you find your app.  Then hold it down until it starts shaking.  Press the red minus in the top left corner of the app to delete the app from that view.  Then open up the app again from the home screen and see if the old shapes are there.  They shouldn't.  If they are, then there is something wrong and you should say something in the comments so someone can help fix the problem.